# fisher's test vs pairwise fisher's test

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I have a fold enrichment table for different days as given below. I need to find the significance of every fold enrichment.

```
fold_enrichment <- matrix(c(0.3,0.43,0.5,0, 0.23,1.3,0.5,1, 1,0,0,6, 0.3,0.5,0.2,2), 4, 4,
              dimnames = list(Day = c("Day1", "Day7", "Day14", "Day28"),
                              Group = c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
```

In R, I tried using `fisher.test(fold_enrichment)` and it gives me a single p-value

> Warning in fisher.test(fold_enrichment) :   'x' has been rounded to
>   integer: Mean relative difference: 0.7652582
>
> Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
>
> data:  fold_enrichment  p-value = 0.6182 alternative hypothesis:
>   two.sided

I have also seen another option

```
pairwise.fisher.test(Day,Group, p.adjust.method="bonferroni")
```

Can anyone suggest me the difference between fisher's test vs pairwise fisher's test and what would be the right solution for my problem?

Comment: These tests are only appropriate for count data (hence the warning in fisher.test()), and it looks like you have something else.

Comment: To give advice on a more appropriate technique we would need to know a bit more about what you are looking for.  Are you interested in whether Groups have different overall levels; different rates of change over time; or something else?

Comment: I would like to know for every group the significance in enrichment rates